# How we can install MySQL-server-community-5.0.51a-0.rhel4.i386.rpm

Tags: linux

How we can install MySQL-server-community-5.0.51a-0.rhel4.i386.rpm and MySQL-client-community-5.0.51a-0.rhel4.i386.rpm on Centos 7?

Comment: As so often, the real question is: What problem are you really trying to solve when attempting this?

Answer (score 7):

The same way you would install other legacy stuff, which RHEL/CentOS 4 and MYSQL 5.0 truly are,  **simply don't**.

Get a current version of MySQL for your CentOS 7.

If you must port and upgrade a CentOS 4 application that really was dependent on that version of MySQL, run a VM with CentOS 4 and install it there. [But you really should not run an expired OS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#End-of-support_schedule)

Comment: Thanks for your update but what i really want know is it possible to install MySQL-server-community-5.0.51a-0.rhel4.i386.rpm and MySQL-client-community-5.0.51a-0.rhel4.i386.rpm on centos 7 if yes, then please show me the step by step procedure.

Comment: That MySQL version is 10 years out-of-date, as is the OS version it is packaged for.CentOS/RHEL4 rpm's are simply not supposed to run on CentOS 7.